# Awk - Adding specific number of spaces between columns

Tags: awk

My input file has columns which are space evenly like so:

```
X a b C D
```

How do I use awk to specify the number of spaces between the columns such that I get something like this:

```
X     a b    C         D
```

I know how to count the spaces between the columns using awk, I just don't know how to add those spaces in order to get the layout I want. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with `awk`

```
$ echo "X a b C D" | awk '{printf "%-6s%-2s%-5s%-9s%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'

X     a b    C        D
```

or with printf directly

```
$ echo "X a b C D" | xargs printf "%-6s%-2s%-5s%-9s%s\n"
X     a b    C        D
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where printf comes in handy:

```
$ echo "X a b C D" | perl -lane 'printf "%-6s%-2s%-5s%-9s%s\n", @F'
X     a b    C        D
```

Adjust the field widths as required.